# Formatting toolbar covered by Android pop-up menu

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, responsive-design

This problem was reproduced in an Android 10 Samsung Galaxy A30s using Gboard or Samsung keyboard, Google Chrome and in more than one community.

When I want to add a link to the two initial rows of an answer, then this is what happens:

[image: selected text with cut/copy/paste menu covering formatting toolbar]

[image: menu covers toolbar even with text on second line]

In other words, a tiny menu appears with functionalities that covers nearly all of the Q&A menu. The most common case for me is wanting to add a link in the first row and then not being able to do it right away. My workarounds are:

- Create extra paragraphs before the text, add the link and then remove the paragraphs.

Or

- Click in the three dots that show up in the right side of that menu to shrink its size as the following two images show. (In this case it'd still cover some icons.)

[image: problem before]

[image: problem after, options are dictionary and Bing search, which only cover right side of toolbar]

This problem happens in questions too but only when the menu format doesn't have this extra row like in the following screenshot.

[image: formatting help toolbar]

Comment: This appears to be the system cut-and-paste functionality of your phone, not under the control of Stackexchange.

Comment: It's about the user experience @EmilJeřábek

Comment: SE can't control the internal features of the OS, the phone in your case. If the cut&paste feature cause trouble, you should use a different keyboard app.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask it's independent of the keyboard I'm using, just checked that now. Either way that's not a nice experience, if that means I have to live with it, then fine. I wrote it here also to check if in other phones the same problem happens because if it's broader, then it surely should have the attention from SE.

Comment: Or how would you have me proceed?

Comment: Maybe something in the settings, e.g. Large Font defined somewhere, which cause the menu to be so huge.... but unlikely SE can do anything about it. Never tried, but if the browser on the phone supports zoom you can try it, though zoom usually breaks the design of SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually drag that "Cut Copy Paste..." menu so that it doesn't obscure the Stack Exchange editor menu. (At least, it's draggable on my Galaxy S9 phone, using the Samsung browser & standard keyboard).

Comment: nice [TIL](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/today-i-learned-til)